# How to link attribute in Yii 2 to another model's field?

Tags: php, activerecord, yii2

I have Products model and ProductProperties via hasOne relation:

```
class Product extends ActiveRecord
{
...
public function getProductProperties()
 {
     return $this->hasOne(ProductProperties::class, ['product_id' => 'id']);
 } 
...
}
```

I had **price** attribute in Products and I want to remove it (including column in database) and to link it to **price**  attribute of ProductProperties model.
Is it possible and how can I do that? First I tried to override **attributes** method like this:

```
    public function fields()
    {
       return [
           'price' => function () {
             return ProductProperties::find(['product_id' => $this->id])->price;
           }
       ]
...
```

but I'm not sure if I can assign values using arrow method. Besides, fields() method uses `$this->price` before it returns anything:

```
public function fields()
    {
    if ($this->price){*some manipulations with price*}
...
    return [
           'price',
            ..*other fields*
    ];
    }
```

The question is How can I remove the price from model and use another model's price attribute without too much pain?

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to show the price, you can do

```
class Product extends ActiveRecord
{
  ...
  public function getProductProperties()
  {
    return $this->hasOne(ProductProperties::class, ['product_id' => 'id']);
  }

  public function getPrice() {
    return $this->productProperties->price;
  }
  ...
}
```

And use it

```
$product = Product::findOne(1);
echo $product->price; // this is a shortcut 
echo $product->productProperties->price; // same as this which is the complete route
```

To save the data, you should first determine how to handle the user data collection, since you have different models and each one has its own validations.

However, if you want to save the price as a Product attribute (I don't recommend it), you could do the following

```
class Product extends ActiveRecord
{
  public $price;
  public function rules () {
    return [
      [['price'], 'integer'] // for massive assignment
    ];
  }

  public function afterFind()
  {
    parent::afterFind();
    $this->price = $this->productProperties->price;
  }

  public function getProductProperties()
  {
    return $this->hasOne(ProductProperties::class, ['product_id' => 'id']);
  }

  public function afterSave($insert, $changedAttributes)
  {
    parent::afterSave($insert, $changedAttributes);
    if (array_key_exists('price', $changedAttributes)) {
      // You should make sure that $this->productProperties exists.
      $this->productProperties->price = $this->price;
      $this->productProperties->save();
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But first I simply added addselect method to Product's constructor. It caused heavy load on mysql so I simply added mysql triggers to copy values from one table to another on change